# Updating google play billing library to version 2 is not working, purchase is always refunded

Tags: android, in-app-billing, play-billing-library

I had a functioning Android implementation in-app billing, using the billing client 1.0.2 library and everything worked fine. I have a simple premium upgrade, without subscriptions.

Now I tried to upgrade to 2.0.3, I made all the necessary changes to my code (using official documentation, release notes, and StackOverflow) and it doesn't work. I know I must recognize all purchases within three days. Failure to correctly recognize purchases will result in reimbursement for these purchases. And that's what I did.

The entire purchase workflow looks okay, the behavior is like before the library is updated. But in the end my purchase is always refunded after 5 minutes (using a trial account, so it's 5 minutes instead of 3 days).

this is inside onPurchasesUpdated:

```
     if (purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
        if (!purchase.isAcknowledged()) {

            AcknowledgePurchaseParams acknowledgePurchaseParams = AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder().setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken()).build();

            AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener = new AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAcknowledgePurchaseResponse(BillingResult billingResult) { 
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Purchase acknowledged", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
            };

            mBillingClient.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams, acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener);
        }
    }
```

The debugger performs recognition and in onAcknowledgePurchaseResponse, I can see that my billingResult response code is 5 (developer error), the debug message is empty. And I have no idea what's wrong. Please, someone can help me find out what's missing. Many thanks!

Comment: Can you see your toast message? You can set a developerPayload. If you can see the payload after acknowledge, then you know it works. There might be a delay because you need to wait for an updated purchase with payload.

Comment: Same problem. I have no idea what is wrong

Comment: Thank you DrPower for your answer. I don't see the toast message, but in debug mode, I can see that the debugger runs into this line. Do I have to use a developer payload? I thought it is optional and I don't have one (https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#attach_a_developer_payload)

Comment: @vadim: please let me know if you found a solution. I tried everything, but I don't have any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating the billing client library to 3.0.0 everything works fine!